# Re-render javascript when form is submitted using rails and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie developing using rails and jquery and having been searching everywhere for a simple example of how to do this for days. I have a page, `poweroutput.html.erb`, that shows the power output of a customer's solar power system for a particular date. When they input a different date, I want them to see different output, but without having to reload the page. On my page I have some javascript as well as a form (for submitting the date for which a user would like to see the power output) as follows:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // a lot of javascript
</script>
</head>

<% form_tag(poweroutput_path, :method=>'post', :id => "date-form", :remote => true ) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(
              'dt', nil,
              {  :id => 'date-field',
                 :class => 'dateformat-d-dt-m-dt-Y',
                 :value => Time.now.getlocal.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")            
              })
    %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

All I want is that the javascript on my page be re-rendered when the form is submitted. My page's controller action is currently as follows:

```
def poweroutput      
  # some code 

  if request.xhr?
    @date = params[:dt]         # dt is posted when form is submitted
  else 
    @date = Time.now.getlocal.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js 
  end
end
```

All I want is for the javascript on my page to be re-rendered with a different `@date` when my form is submitted. Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Do you actually want to call a javascript function when the form submits or when the user changes the value? Is there any JS on the form right now, and are you using jQuery?

Comment: The page shows the power output of a customer's solar power system for a particular day. When they input a different date, I want them to see different output, but without having to reload the page. Sorry, I'll try to edit my question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a lot of javascript, then:

1. Put the date somewhere in the web page (v.g., a hidden field)
2. Modify the javascript so it gets the value from there.
3. Create a separated .js library for the JavaScript, and load it in the page.

That way the browser will profit from caching the javascript, reducing both the load in your server and download time for the page.

Comment: Why would you load an entire JS file when what he wants is already on the page> You just need to bind a function to the forms submit function and you are good to go.

Comment: It's actually not that much javascript--maybe 150 lines. And everything is working fine on first load. I just don't know how to get the javascript to be rendered again when I submit the form. The javascript uses the @date variable from the controller action. And this variable changes after I submit the form. And I'd like for the javascript to rerender to reflect the new @date.

Comment: @Devin M. I just did that and it re-rendered! For other newbies out there, I just copied and pasted the functions for application.js in Ryan Bates' Railscast #136. Maybe someone else can say why, but for some reason even with these appropriate functions in application.js, the js in my poweroutput.html.erb was not rerendering when a poweroutput.js.erb existed. So I just deleted the .js.erb and now the js within script tags on poweroutput.html.erb is rerendering. Now I have another problem though.

Comment: o woops. I spoke too soon. Well the javascript is rerendering, but not executing. How can I make it execute?

Comment: What do you mean it is rendering the js on poweroutput.html.erb?

Comment: yes it is just rerendering poweroutput.html.erb (and the js is the only thing that changes in this). I know this doesn't seem very efficient, but I'm desperately grasping for something/anything that will make things work right now.